# find_under_expand with regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there a way to trigger 'find_under_expand' (Ctrl+D) on a regex search?

What I could do today is do a regex search and click on 'Find All' and that selects all the occurrences matching my pattern. But what I am looking to achieve is select occurrence-by-occurrence with Ctrl+D as we can do with non-regex expressions.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you need the `Ctrl+d` on search expressions for?

Comment: I have a huge file that contains the same pattern in different parts and not the same modifications should be done on all matching patterns. So, I have to select sub-set by sub-set to modify progressively. One solution is to split the file by sub-set and benefit from 'Find All' patterns, but I just was wondering if there was a way to select with Ctrl+D with regex, it would be way better

Comment: In the end I managed to make my modifications less painfully than I imagined, by selecting the targeted search part and using `Find All` on it

Comment: Maybe [conditional regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) matches could have done the trick here.

Comment: In my particular case, this couldn't help me as the pattern is exactly the same. What differs is how to edit..